# Play java list of object

Tags: forms, list, for-loop, playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm using play 2.1 with Java and ebean ORM. I've got a Question object that let's say contains 2 String : title and answer

The user create a bunch of questions that are stocked with no answer.

Then i get back this list, and I display it on a view :

```
@(list : Lis[Question])
...
@for(toto<-list)
<td>@toto.title</td>
<td>     ?     </td>
```

I would like the user to fill an answer on the '?' and that with an appropriate method, a new Question is created with the title and the answer.

Either I create this method and I put it in the for boucle. Issue : the user has to validate every answer by clicking on each button... (any ideas to have a button that activate all the others??)

Or I've tried to update the list that I display with a dynamicForm and then get it back then I could do whatever I want, but I didn't succeed..

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can use javascript/AJAX for that, so then you can send request per each item separately, without need of still re-rendering the whole page

Comment: I've looked into the javascript, and there is ways to create dynamically a form (add as many requests as we want dynamically) but would it be possible to submit all of them in a row?

Comment: Does anyone know how to use @inputText(myForm("myattribute")) for the form requests in play, except that the attribute is an element of a String List (and not a simple attribute)?